# Use ionic 4 plugin in Cordova Typescript project

Tags: typescript, cordova, cordova-plugins

i'm trying to use  [cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) 
to my Cordova typescript project, but i can't find how can i use javascript plugin in typescript project.
Maybe it'll be easier to use i[onic plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus#usage) in cordova Angular + Typescript project? (BTW. it is the same plugin).
Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/jimijings11/cordova-plugin-googleLogin) plugin (based on [cordova-plugin-googlePlu](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus)s), but with types.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Ionic4**, just check the plugin available for **Ionic platform** 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus, it will provides for you a documentation or installation and how to use it into your code with typescript

Comment: Hi. No ionic4. Simply cordova with typescript.

Comment: I think it's not provided yet you can check open issues https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/231